# Replace ids from file1 with that of file2

Tags: awk, sed, fasta

I have two text files and I want to replace id from file1 with that of file2. All the ids are in the same order in both the files.

```
File1
>12_abc
ghfghfjgfhjgfjf
hgfjfgjgfjfgjgfjf
>13_def
ghfghgfgfgfghfjhf
nmbnmbhjgkjgjhggh
>14_ghi
uytghhuytuytuytuyt
ytrftyfrghfhgfgfgg

File2
>12_abc|10
>13_def|20
>14_ghi|30

Desired Output
>12_abc|10
ghfghfjgfhjgfjf
hgfjfgjgfjfgjgfjf
>13_def|20
ghfghgfgfgfghfjhf
nmbnmbhjgkjgjhggh
>14_ghi|30
uytghhuytuytuytuyt
ytrftyfrghfhgfgfgg
```

`awk '{print} !(NR%2) {if ((getline < "File2.txt") > -1) print}' File1`

Answer (score 2):

This looks awkwardly a lot as a FASTA file. This is how I would do it:

**If you want to replace the name in order:**

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[FNR]=$0;next}/^>/{print a[++c]; next}1' File2 File1 > File1.new
```

**If you want to replace the name based on the content:**

```
awk -F '|' '(NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0;next}/^>/{print a[$0]; next}1' File2 File1 > File1.new
```